# Languages recognized by finite state automata of polynomially growing size

Tags: formal-languages, reference-request, finite-automata

In the course of my research (condensed matter physics stuff), I stumbled over the following concept:

---

The class of regular languages can be defined via finite state machines (FSM):
A language $L$ is regular iff there is an FSM which accepts $L$.
Clearly every **finite** language is regular.

I am interested in the following (larger) class of languages (call it $\mathcal{L}^?$) over some finite alphabet $\Sigma$ with relaxed conditions:

> A language $L$ is in $\mathcal{L}^?$ $:\Leftrightarrow$
>
> There is a **sequence** of FSMs $(M_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that
>
> 1. $w\in L\,\Leftrightarrow\,$ $M_{|w|}(w)$ accepts
> 2. $|M_n|\leq \operatorname{Poly}(n)$
>
> Here $|w|$ denotes the length of word $w$ and $|M|$ is the size of the
>   FSM $M$, i.e., its number of states.

Obviously all languages $L\subseteq \Sigma^\ast$ are included if one drops the second requirement, as the sublanguages $L_n\subseteq L$ of words with fixed length $n$ are finite. But for a generic language $L_n$ with fixed length words, the minimal accepting FSA has a size exponentially growing in $n$ (is this correct? I sketched just a naive counting argument...).

---

As I'm no computer scientist, I was wondering whether this concept is already known in automata theory / computability theory (and if so, how it is called). Due to my lack of expertise, I just do not know where to start.

I would be very happy if you could ...

- either provide a pointer to the relevant topic of automata theory (terms I have to look for, relevant publications)
- or give an alternative characterization of this class (maybe it's just equivalent to one of the well-known language classes?)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The relevant area is computational complexity, though I've never heard of this particular circuit model. Your class is a subset of L/poly, though probably much smaller.

Comment: the problem is probably fairly closely related to counting isomorphisms of graphs of given sizes.... yes this question has been asked before, [Languages recognized by polynomial-size DFAs](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22424/languages-recognized-by-polynomial-size-dfas) (cstheory.se) and is apparently mostly open & studied only somewhat peripherally

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: +1 for pointing to L/poly. I am going to read about it.

Comment: @vzn: +1 for providing the reference to cstheory.se. Seems there is work to do for the theoretical computer scientists, thought. I'll have a look at the (few) references suggested there.

Comment: @NcLang : $\:$ Are FSMs allowed to go backwards over the input? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: So far I thought about this concept only in the context of "standard" deterministic finite automata (so everything it "knows" about the previously read letters must be stored in the states). What would be the consequences of your modification?

Comment: My modification would make the resulting class _equal_ to L/poly, since the logarithmic-size read/write tapes can only take on polynomially many values and there are only polynomially many possible positions for the head that reads the advice tape. $\;$